# Sourcetree do merge in wrong direction

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

In sourcetree version <=3.2.1 (MacOs) I have following problem

When I was on branch A (e.g. master-test) and click on Icon Merge on top bar

[image]

and window appear (below screenshot is AFTER whole operation but similar options was choosen)

[image]

and I choose branch B (e.g "master") in "Pick a commit..." subwindow and then I click "ok"

After that operation and push it to origin (bitbucket) I see that I loose information about previous commits for branch A. I also notice that I have wrong automatic message in merge commit (it is seen on above picture)

> Merged A into B

but I merged B into A (!). The output result is that B was merged into A with wrong merge message and I loose B previous commits history (but commits exists but they are "shifted" to branch A).

I don't get whats happen? I was able to reproduce this problem (allways). I solve this problem and put answer below - bot still I don't know whats going on and why Sourcetree "change" direction of merging - and I will be glad If someone can explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sourcetree start merging in such "wrong" way until I accidentally try make merge in alternative way

[image]

This way works as expected merge master into master-test with automatic commit message (and without loosing branch history):

> Merged master into master-test

After that the approach described in question starts to work also as excected